# Ввод и вывод данных не через консоль

Tags: python

Подскажите пожалуйста с помощью чего и как я мог бы вводить и выводить данные в красивое окошечко.

Comment: Tkinter, PyQt, PyGTK, PyGame, ncurses, да и вообще это хорошо гуглится

Comment: одним словом вам нужно GUI. Как это выглядит, может зависеть от платформы, можете веб-страничку создать и в браузере вводить данные, можете мобильное приложение, чтобы совсем красивенько на планшетах, телефонах данные вводить и конечно куча GUI библиотек для настольных компьютеров существует (может вам лучше существующее приложение типа MS Excel или LibreOffice Calc проэксплуатировать, чтобы табличные данные вводить, а потом только результат дальше вашему скрипту скармливать).